# PHP how to group and count elements of inner array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Can someone please explain how to obtain this result from the following array?  Here is the result I am looking for:

```
Array
(
    [Nov 18, 2011] => Array
        (
            [C] => 2
            [I] => 1
        )

    [Nov 22, 2011] => Array
        (
            [C] => 2
        )

)
```

And here is the array with the raw data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Nov 18, 2011] => C
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Nov 18, 2011] => C
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Nov 18, 2011] => I
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Nov 22, 2011] => C
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Nov 22, 2011] => C
                )

        )

)
```

The first array shown represents the the count of items for each element of the inner array, which is what I am trying to summarize from the next array. Thanks.

- EDIT -

Here is the query which generates the above arra:

```
$qrybilled = $this->db->query("SELECT tbltc.BILLED FROM tbltc WHERE tbltc.PN = $pn AND tbltc.Y = $taxyear AND tbltc.SCENARIO = $scenario GROUP BY BILLED");
$x = 0; $arr_billed = array();

foreach ($qrybilled->result() as $row) {
$qry3 = $this->db->query("SELECT tbltc.* FROM tbltc WHERE tbltc.PN = $pn AND tbltc.Y = $taxyear AND tbltc.SCENARIO = $scenario AND tbltc.BILLED = '".$row->BILLED."' GROUP BY TC ORDER BY CAT ASC, TC ASC");

    $tmp3 = array();
    foreach ($qry3->result() as $row) {     
        $tmp3[] = array( date("M d, Y",strtotime($row->BILLED)) => $row->CAT);
    }
    $arr_billed3[] = $tmp3; 

}
$data['billed3'] = $arr_billed3;
```

Comment: Where are you getting this data from? a database? if so, you can use `GROUP BY` from the query and have the result presented to you in that way.

Comment: Will the inner array always have very clear, fixed values (ie. 'C' and 'I'), or will they have dynamic values?

Comment: Yes, values are coming from a database, and yes, the inner array will always be either 'C' or 'I' or 'M'.

Comment: @Truth, I am just having trouble with combining the GROUP BY with some kind of count.  I don't just want to GROUP BY, but I also need to know the count per grouping level.

Comment: Please show us the query generating this output. We'll be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Iterated trips to the database is not ideal and is too demanding on resources.  You should refactor this earlier step to incorporate JOINs to make just one trip to the database.  SQL is perfectly qualified to perform grouping and counting as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$arr[0][] = array('Nov 18, 2011'=>'C');
$arr[0][] = array('Nov 18, 2011'=>'C');
$arr[0][] = array('Nov 18, 2011'=>'I');

$arr[1][] = array('Nov 22, 2011'=>'C');
$arr[1][] = array('Nov 22, 2011'=>'C');

$result = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    foreach($value as $k=>$v){
        foreach($v as $_k=>$_v){
            if(isset($result[$_k][$_v])){
                $result[$_k][$_v]++;
            }
            else {
                $result[$_k][$_v] =1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Array result:**

```
print_r($result);

Array
(
    [Nov 18, 2011] => Array
        (
            [C] => 2
            [I] => 1
        )

    [Nov 22, 2011] => Array
        (
            [C] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: Wow!  That's awesome, thank you so much for that.  Now I just have to figure out what is happening there.  Can you tell me what is the difference between $k and $_k, or between $v and $_v?  What is the significance of the underscore?  @Oyeme

Comment: Underscore in variable $_k and $_v - it's just a variable name.Nothing special :).(Deep an array itteration)

Answer (score -1):

```
$food = array('0' => array('orange', 'banana', 'apple','jack'),
              '1' => array('carrot', 'collard', 'pea'));

echo count($food); // output 2

echo count($food[0]) // output 4

echo count($food[1]) // output 3
```